# Is passing an object as a parameter to a friend function in cpp compulsory?

Tags: c++

I was wondering about a friend function that, Is passing an object as a parameter to a friend function in cpp compulsory?

Can't we just access the members of the class directly? as we are declared as friends?

1. Reverse a Number using C++.

Their code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class numberRev{
    int n, i;
    friend void rev(numberRev n);
    public:
       void getData(int num){
           n = num;
       }
};

void rev(numberRev r){
    int i, rem;
    while(r.n>0){
        rem = r.n%10;
        cout<<rem;
        r.n = r.n/10;
    }
}

int main() {
    numberRev r;
    r.getData(1234);
    rev(r);
    return 0;
}
```

The output they get:

```
4321
```

According to me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class numberRev{
    int n, i;
    friend void rev();
    public:
       void getData(int num){
           n = num;
       }
};

void rev(){
    int i, rem;
    while(n>0){
        rem = n%10;
        cout<<rem;
        n = n/10;
    }
}

int main() {
    numberRev r;
    r.getData(1234);
    rev();
    return 0;
}
```

The output I got:

```
ERROR!
g++ /tmp/HnSzEG2SqI.cpp
/tmp/HnSzEG2SqI.cpp: In function 'void rev()':
/tmp/HnSzEG2SqI.cpp:16:11: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
   16 |     while(n>0){
      |
```

Give a simple and understandable answer plz.....

Comment: Friend function is not a member function, it doesn't get the implicit `this` argument. Why do you want it to be a friend at all?

Comment: `numberRev a, b; rev();` - which of the two instances would it access and why?

Comment: You could make the friend access private static data... but I'd say it's overall worse than a static member function doing the same thing.

Comment: I think you're confusing classes (i.e. types) with objects (i.e. values).

Comment: Do you mean "what's a difference between a friend function and  class method", like  `NumberRev::rev() { while (n > 0) .... }` ?

Comment: Suppose you also had `class A { int n; friend void rev(); };`. Which `n` would `rev` access and why? (If you're thinking of some "common sense" explanation along the lines of "there's only one class and one object in the program, and that is the only thing that has an `n`, so *obviously* that's what it should access", that's not how computer programs work.)

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what it means to be a friend. Here

> ```
> class numberRev{
>     int n, i;
>     friend void rev();
>     public:
>        void getData(int num){
>            n = num;
>        }
> };
> ```

You declare the free function `void rev()` to be a friend of the class. The function `rev` is a free function; it is not a member of that class. Hence here:

> ```
> void rev(){
>     int i, rem;
>     while(n>0){
>         rem = n%10;
>         cout<<rem;
>         n = n/10;
>     }
> }
> ```

You seem to expect that `n` refers to member of an instance of type `numberRev`. But there is no such instance in the function. `n` is undeclared. Just like in any other function you can create an instance and use it:

```
void rev(){
    int i, rem;
    numberRev nr;
    nr.getData(42);
    while(nr.n>0){
        rem = nr.n%10;
        cout<<rem;
        nr.n = nr.n/10;
    }
}
```

Because the function is a friend, it can directly access the private members of `nr`.

You do declare an instance in `main`, but that has no relation to what you do in the function `rev`. It does not work like you think it does for several reasons:

- Suppose you declared two instances in `main`, which one would `while(n>0)` refer to, and why?
- A free function can be friend of many classes. You expect that making it a friend automatically makes it a member of the class, but a function can only be member function of a single class.

TL;DR: No it is not necessary to pass an instance of `numberRev` to the friend function. As shown in the example above, you can create an instance also inside the function. If however there is no instance at all, there is no point in declaring the function a friend.